# Block docker access to specific IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, google-compute-engine

I'd like my EC2 instance to have IAM-based permissions, but don't want the docker containers on that instance to have the same permissions. I believe it should be sufficient to block access to the magic IP `169.254.169.254`. Is it sufficient to run:

`iptables -I DOCKER -s 169.254.169.254 -j DROP`

Do I also need to configure my docker daemon with `--icc=false` or `--iptables=false`?

Comment: docker manage network access rules by editing the iptables rules of the host bridge. Adding more rules on the docker bridge should be sufficient.

Comment: The documentation says "Docker will not delete or modify any pre-existing rules from the DOCKER filter chain. This allows the user to create in advance any rules required to further restrict access to the containers."

Comment: exactly, so adding your DROP iptables rule will be used by the bridge.

Comment: Can someone post an example how he achieved it? Logging in to the host and use `iptables -A DOCKER -p tcp -d 169.254.169.254 -j DROP` is not solving it for me.

Comment: @CarlAmbroselli are you testing from inside a container?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally got this working, you need to add this rule on the host machine:

1) Drop docker bridge packets when outbound to `169.254.169.254` port 80 or 443.

```sh
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -i docker0 -d 169.254.169.254 \
  -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j DROP
```

Now, if I try to connect inside the container:

```
$ sudo docker run -it ubuntu bash
root@8dc525dc5a04:/# curl -I https://www.google.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
root@8dc525dc5a04:/# curl -I http://169.254.169.254/
  # <-- hangs indefinitely, which is what we want
```

Connections to the special IP still work from the host machine, but not from inside containers.

Note: my use case is for Google Compute Engine and prevents Docker containers from accessing the metadata server on `169.254.169.254`, while still allowing DNS and other queries against that same IP. Your mileage may vary on AWS.

Answer (score 9):

I would recommend the following variation on the accepted answer:

```
sudo iptables \
        --insert DOCKER-USER \
        --destination 169.254.169.254 \
        --jump REJECT
```

The reason for this is that the above command adds the rule to the `DOCKER-USER` chain which Docker is guaranteed not to modify.

Sources:

- https://ops.tips/blog/blocking-docker-containers-from-ec2-metadata/
- https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/

Comment: The advantage of this answer with respect to the accepted one is that by rejecting the connection, the caller has a negative response and fails immediately. Silently dropping the packets as done in the accepted answer has the effect of timing out the connection. If this is a synchronous process (usually it is), it will be stuck for the duration of the timeout.